# TC - how to assert on <img src=>

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, assert

I'm trying to use `selenium webdriver` to assert a

```
logo.svg == context.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='../logo.svg']"
```

on Python3.

So, when I'm running the testcase I get:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
      selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//img[@src='../logo.svg']"}
```

Snapshot of the HTML:

[image: HTML]

I been trying to "find" this particular image on a header with no success. Can anyone help me?

#----
reviwing the issue, logo_company = logo.svg is a string and context.driver.find_element_by..... it's the imagin object. I thinking how can i compare string == string or, maybe, the file.svg == context.driver that return file.svg something like that?

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) seems to be a bit off. To locate the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath A`:

  ```
  context.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[starts-with(@src, '/static/media/logo-Caja-los-andes')]")
  ```
- `css_selector A`:

  ```
  context.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[src^='/static/media/logo-Caja-los-andes']")
  ```
- `xpath B`:

  ```
  context.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[starts-with(@src, '/static/media/logo-Caja-los-andes') and @alt='Logo Caja Los Andes']")
  ```
- `css_selector B`:

  ```
  context.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[src^='/static/media/logo-Caja-los-andes'][alt='Logo Caja Los Andes']")
  ```